# 3D model modifier embeded in website

Tags: 3d, web, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I am building a furniture website that also sells custom furniture.

I want to have a section in the website where visitors can choose from a variety of options such as dimensions, material, handles, etc. and have a 3D model update as they go along.

There would be too massive amount of 3D models we would have to generate if we simply tried to make one for every combination of options.

So my idea is to use a program to build a base model that can be manipulated in those ways by user input.

So simply any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please explain about what you have done to reach your goal and the problems that you had.

Comment: Not much unfortunately, just been looking online for different options and haven't found any. I don't really know where to start...

Comment: I was hoping to use something like sketch-up to create the model? and then use rules to modify the length of sides, colours etc. based on user input.

Comment: ok, try it, and if you had a problem, come here and ask about it with your written code.

Comment: in this place, we talk about problems of users and their resolutions, the answer to the question that you asked is based on users different experiences and wont show you a complete answer, you must first try to find some resolution by yourself by searching via search engines like Google, and when you had a problem using them you can ask here.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll see what I come up with. Still open to ideas if someone wants to offer them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described sounds like a "product configuration". It is possible to create such using [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) and [Three.js](https://threejs.org/). I think these are enough keywords for you to now search on the Internet.

For some demos see : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnOIhf4OyPc
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-create-a-dynamic-product-configurator/2336